# Keeping the quotes when reading CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv, quotes

Truoble with a really annoying homework. I have a csv-file with lots of comma-delimitered fields per row. I need to take the last two fields from every row and write them into a new txt-file. The problem is that some of the latter fields have sentences, those with commas are in double quotes, those without them aren't. For example:

> 180,easy
>
> 240min,"Quite easy, but number 3, wtf?"
>
> 300,much easier than the last assignment

I did this and it worked just fine, but the double quotes disappear. The assignment is to copy the fields to the txt-file, use semicolon as delimiter and remove possible line breaks. The text must remain exactly the same. We have an automatic check system, so it's no use arguing if this makes any sense.

```
import csv
file = open('myfile.csv', 'r')
output= open('mytxt.txt', 'w')
csvr = csv.reader(file)
headline = next(csvr)
for line in csvr:
    lgt = len(line)
    time = line[lgt - 2].replace('\n', '')
    feedb = line[lgt - 1].replace('\n', '')
    if time != '' and feedb != '':
        output.write(time + ';' + feedb + '\n')
output.close()
file.close()
```

Is there some easy solution for this? Can I use csv module at all? No one seems to have exactly the same problem.

Thank you all beforehand.

Comment: I am not sure that this place is the best choice to do your homework! Maybe talking to your teacher would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import csv
file = open('myfile.csv', 'r')
output= open('mytxt.txt', 'w')
csvr = csv.reader(file)
headline = next(csvr)
for line in csvr:
    lgt = len(line)
    time = line[lgt - 2].replace('\n', '')
    feedb = line[lgt - 1].replace('\n', '')
    if time != '' and feedb != '':
        if ',' in feedb:
            output.write(time + ';"' + feedb + '"\n')
        else:
            output.write(time + ';' + feedb + '\n')
output.close()
file.close()
```

Comment: Very simple, it worked for some lines. The file must be even messier than I thought. I'm still wondering, are there any build-in methods in python's csv keep the quoted texts untouched...

Comment: Are you able to share the CSV? This may help us find a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Had to do it the ugly way, the file was too irrational. Talked with some collaegues on the same course and apparently the idea was NOT to use csv module here, but to rehearse basic file handling in Python.

```
file = open('myfile.csv','r')
output = open('mytxt.txt', 'w')
headline = file.readline()
feedb_lst = []
count = 0
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('1'): #found out all lines should start with an ID number,
        data_lst = line.split(',', 16) #that always starts with '1'
        lgt = len(data_lst)
        time = data_lst[lgt - 2]
        feedb = data_lst[lgt - 1].rstrip()
        feedback = [time, feedb]
        feedb_lst.append(feedback)
        count += 1
    else:
        feedb_lst[count - 1][1] = feedb_lst[count - 1][1] + line.rstrip()
i = 1
for item in feedb_lst:
    if item[0] != '' and item[1] != '':
        if i == len(feedb_lst):
            output.write(item[0] + ';' + item[1])
        else:
            output.write(item[0] + ';' + item[1] + '\n')
    i += 1
output.close()
file.close()
```

Thank you for your help!